# Detect rejected promises from Express route handlers during testing

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

When an Express async route handler throws an error (which it does not catch), then it will not be passed to `next()`, so will not end up in an error handling middleware.

I want to simulate that in a test:

```
import * as request from "supertest";

const router = express.Router();
router.route("/boom").post(async (req, res, next) => { throw new Error(); });
router.use((err, req, res, next) => { res.status(500).json("caught!"); });

const app = express();
app.use(router);

test("uncaught error"), done => {
  request(app)
    .post("/boom")
    .end((err, res) => {               // never gets here
      expect(err).toBeTruthy();
      expect(res.status).not.toBe(500);
      expect(res.body).not.toBe("caught!");
      done();
    });
});
```

However even in the test, the error is uncaught, and times out. So the test fails.

How can I detect this?

---

*(BTW: supertest does integration testing... can I do it without supertest, just a Jest unit test?)*

Comment: I would expect `new Error()` to be caught by Jest as unhandled rejection and fail the test. Unit test would involve exporting route handler function and making sure that it doesn't return rejected promise.